# php sql report shows same person in all classes

Tags: php, report, multiple-tables

I am trying to make a report that will show attendance of who was present in each class by date.

My tables only have each person present in one class.

But my php sql report shows same person in all classes.

Tables -  attendant_record, _person, _person_group

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM _person, attendance_record, _person_group WHERE _person.id = attendance_record.personid ORDER BY 
attendance_record.date';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Attendance Report</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <caption class="title">Attendance Report</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Present</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo '<tr>
                  <td>'.$row['personid'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$row['present'].'</td>
                  <td>'. date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['date'])) . '</td></tr>
';
        $no++;
    }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image of result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/002Tp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the SQL query to select only the group of each person.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM _person, attendance_record, _person_group WHERE 
_person.id = attendance_record.personid 
 AND
_person.group_id = _person_group.group_id
ORDER BY 
attendance_record.date';
```

This will select only records from the group table that match the each person.
I assumed the column name **group_id** but you can change to what is your column name.

**EDIT:** to filter by date use something like this (order by date is no longer needed if all dates are the same).

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM _person, attendance_record, _person_group WHERE 
_person.id = attendance_record.personid 
 AND
_person.group_id = _person_group.group_id
 AND
_attendance_record.date = '2018-09-08';
```

Comment: @Billh  you should test your SQL queries first, directly on the database before putting the results on a web page. This is much easier. What database are you using? Most have a facility to test queries.... like mySQL workbench.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean on running the code directly on the database in phpMyadmin. Nice!
This is the code that worked.                                                                         
SELECT * FROM _person, attendance_record, _person_group         WHERE 
_person.id = attendance_record.personid 
 AND
attendance_record.groupid = _person_group.id 
ORDER BY 
attendance_record.date                                                                                                                 I would like to be able to filter it by date      Last Sunday

Comment: @billh Ah ok its working now? Please accept answer and vote up using the arrows so others can see its answered.  Also... to filter by by date just add another criteria to the WHERE clause like  "AND attendance_record.date = 'desired date'.